# in box2d, how could I extend/shrink a joint with a body attached to end while keeping all momentum, angles, positions, etc?

Tags: box2d, physics, 2d-games

Please see Diagram:

[swing diagram](http://i46.tinypic.com/2zhmsgo.png)

In box2D I am trying to think of a way I can attach a pivoting arm to the blue box and have the pivot arm extend or shrink.

The blue box is setup to go left and right using a prismatic joint to act as a track/rail. As the blue box moves left and right the momentum will cause the swing arm to swing. I have this working fine.

My issue is that I can't reliably think of a way to move the bottom green box up and down the swing arm. If the player presses up, I want it so that the bottom green box will move up the swing arm. If the player stops pressing up then the bottom green box will stop and remain wherever it was along the swing arm. I want to do this but keep the momentum of the swing arm.

I would only render a line between the blue box and bottom green box, so it would appear that it is extending or contracting.

I have tried prismatic joint and distance joint, but when I set the new limit or distance for the joint it doesn't have a fluid motion. The joint doesn't act rigid enough. For example, when shortening the prismatic joint I can't figure out how I can reposition the bottom green box at the end of the new joint length but still keep the momentum and rotation it previously had.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I would have expected that setting new limits (changing them gradually of course) would have worked ok. How about using the motor of the prismatic joint, that would be another way to do it, and might give a bit more realistic looking result.

Answer (score -1):

It will be hard for me to give you code without seeing what you have done already. But the solution to your problem is to use... Math.

Calculating the speed at which a pendulum swings is actually a [well-known problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum#Period_of_oscillation). The "period" is the time it takes for a pendulum to complete one down-and-back swing, and the equation that governs the speed of a pendulum is:

```
T = 2*PI*sqrt(L/g)    where "L" is the length of the pendulum
```

So, if you can parametrize your problem this way, as the user moves the green box "up" that will reduce `L` and the the period of oscillation (`T`) will go down, so the pendulum will speed up.

As a side note, if you want the blue box to be able to move around, then what you have is known as a [compound pendulum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum#Compound_pendulum) and your equation for the period of oscillation of the pendulum will be modified to:

```
T = 2*PI*sqrt(I/mgR)    where "R" is the adjusted length of the pendulum
```

where I is the moment of inertia of the box, and is equal to:

```
I = (m/6) * h^2         where h is the length of one side of the blue box
```

Comment: 4.5 years after my answer was posted, someone decided to down vote it?  Perhaps leave a comment to explain WHY.